# How to add extra command line arguments to createsuperuser - Django?

Tags: python, django

I have UserManager class below:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('The Email must be set'))
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)        
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_staff=True.'))
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.'))
        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

In the create_superuser function, i would like to add one more field to set tenant_id. This has to be taken from the command line, when using `python manage.py createsuperuser`.

If i add tenant_id in create_superuser function like this:

```
create_superuser(self, email, password, tenant_id, **extra_fields):
```

I'm getting the following error

> UserManager.create_superuser() missing 1 required positional argument: 'tenant_id'.

Is there any way i can pass tenant_id from command line?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to add it to create user aswell, like this:

```
 class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
        def create_user(self, tenant_id email, password, **extra_fields):
            if not email:
                raise ValueError(_("The Email must be set"))
            email = self.normalize_email(email)
            user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
            return user
    
        def create_superuser(self, tenant_id email, password, **extra_fields):
            extra_fields.setdefault("is_staff", True)
            extra_fields.setdefault("is_superuser", True)
            extra_fields.setdefault("is_active", True)
    
            if extra_fields.get("is_staff") is not True:
                raise ValueError(_("Superuser must have is_staff=True."))
            if extra_fields.get("is_superuser") is not True:
                raise ValueError(_("Superuser must have is_superuser=True."))
            return self.create_user(tenant_id email, password, **extra_fields)
```

and in **models.py** insert these lines:

```
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['tenant_id', 'email', 'password']

objects = UserManager()
```

Answer (score 0):

Feras Alfrih's suggestion with `REQUIRED_FIELDS` is one way as suggested in the documentation.

Another possibility:

> You can subclass the management command and override get_input_data()
> if you want to customize data input and validation. Consult the source
> code for details on the existing implementation and the method’s
> parameters. For example, it could be useful if you have a ForeignKey
> in REQUIRED_FIELDS and want to allow creating an instance instead of
> entering the primary key of an existing instance.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/django-admin/#createsuperuser